# Изменить локаль приложения

Tags: java, swing, локаль

Текстовые значения хранятся в `ResourceBundle`, которая в начале программы определена вот так:

```
private final static ResourceBundle BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages");
```

Тогда все элементы получают свои текстовые значения из BUNDLE, например кнопка:

```
JButton buttonPlay = new JButton(BUNDLE.getString("IntroWindow.buttonPlay.text"));
```

Вопрос: Как во время исполнения программы изменить локаль приложения?
Т.е. чтобы все забирали текст не из `ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages")`, а из `ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages_fr")` ? (пример для французского)

Comment: Когда-то пытался - мне не удалось.

Пришлось делать все надписи "вручную".

Answer (score 1):

В `classpath` добавляете `messages_fr.properties`

```
language=fran\u00E7ais
```

Подменяете BUNDLE

```
BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", Locale.FRANCE);
System.out.println(BUNDLE.getString("language"));
```

Вывод:

> français

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
```